# "Anti-merge" in pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, merge

How can I pick out the difference between to columns of the same name in two dataframes?
I mean I have dataframe A with a column named X and dataframe B with column named X, if i do `pd.merge(A, B, on=['X'])`, i'll get the common X values of A and B, but how can i get the "non-common" ones?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you change the merge type to `how='outer'` and `indicator=True` this will add a column to tell you whether the values are left/both/right only:

```
In [2]:
A = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(5)})
B = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(3,8)})
print(A)
print(B)
   x
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
   x
0  3
1  4
2  5
3  6
4  7

In [3]:
pd.merge(A,B, how='outer', indicator=True)

Out[3]:
     x      _merge
0  0.0   left_only
1  1.0   left_only
2  2.0   left_only
3  3.0        both
4  4.0        both
5  5.0  right_only
6  6.0  right_only
7  7.0  right_only
```

You can then filter the resultant merged df on the `_merge` col:

```
In [4]:
merged = pd.merge(A,B, how='outer', indicator=True)
merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']

Out[4]:
     x     _merge
0  0.0  left_only
1  1.0  left_only
2  2.0  left_only
```

You can also use `isin` and negate the mask to find values not in B:

```
In [5]:
A[~A['x'].isin(B['x'])]

Out[5]:
   x
0  0
1  1
2  2
```

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer gives a so called `LEFT JOIN IF NULL` in SQL terms. If you want all the rows except the matching ones from **both** DataFrames, not only left. You have to add another condition to the filter, since you want to exclude all rows which are in `both`.

In this case we use `DataFrame.merge` & `DataFrame.query`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcde')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('cdefgh')})

print(df1, '\n')
print(df2)

   A
0  a # <- only df1
1  b # <- only df1
2  c # <- both
3  d # <- both
4  e # <- both

   A 
0  c # both
1  d # both
2  e # both
3  f # <- only df2
4  g # <- only df2
5  h # <- only df2
```

```
df = (
    df1.merge(df2, 
              on='A', 
              how='outer', 
              indicator=True)
    .query('_merge != "both"')
    .drop(columns='_merge')
)

print(df)

   A
0  a
1  b
5  f
6  g
7  h
```