# Anti-Join Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, anti-join

I have two tables and I would like to append them so that only all the data in table A is retained and data from table B is only added if its key is unique (Key values are unique in table A and B however in some cases a Key will occur in both table A and B).

I think the way to do this will involve some sort of filtering join (anti-join) to get values in table B that do not occur in table A then append the two tables.

I am familiar with R and this is the code I would use to do this in R.

```
library("dplyr")

## Filtering join to remove values already in "TableA" from "TableB"
FilteredTableB <- anti_join(TableB,TableA, by = "Key")

## Append "FilteredTableB" to "TableA"
CombinedTable <- bind_rows(TableA,FilteredTableB)
```

How would I achieve this in python?

Comment: By key do you mean row index, column index, or cell?

Comment: By key i mean a column contained in both tables with values to merge on.

Comment: I've added an answer. Please let me know what you think via feedback, and if it solves your exercise. Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected input and desired output?

Comment: I keep being amazed at how intuitive and elegant dplyr makes data processing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Anti-merge" in pandas (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242368/anti-merge-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Consider the following dataframes

```
TableA = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 3),
                      pd.Index(list('abcd'), name='Key'),
                      ['A', 'B', 'C']).reset_index()
TableB = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 3),
                      pd.Index(list('aecf'), name='Key'),
                      ['A', 'B', 'C']).reset_index()
```

---

```
TableA
```

[image]

---

```
TableB
```

[image]

This is one way to do what you want

#### Method 1

```
# Identify what values are in TableB and not in TableA
key_diff = set(TableB.Key).difference(TableA.Key)
where_diff = TableB.Key.isin(key_diff)

# Slice TableB accordingly and append to TableA
TableA.append(TableB[where_diff], ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

#### Method 2

```
rows = []
for i, row in TableB.iterrows():
    if row.Key not in TableA.Key.values:
        rows.append(row)

pd.concat([TableA.T] + rows, axis=1).T
```

---

#### Timing

**4 rows with 2 overlap**

Method 1 is much quicker

[image]

**10,000 rows 5,000 overlap**

**loops are bad**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just had a look at the documentation for combine_first and it seems to be kind of what I am looking for. 
However, how do I specify the column to combine on (key)? For each row in Table B I want it to check the value in the "Key" column and if that value is contained in Table A's "Key" column I want to ignore that row in B.  Where there is a key value in table B that is not in Table A I want to append that row from Table B.

Comment: @Ayelavan after thinking about it, I cannot recommend `combine_first`.  The problem being that if a key exist in A but some of the columns are null, those nulls might be filled in by B's values with same key.  the answer to the question you posed in comments is that `combine_first` expects the key to be in the index.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: You can simplify Method 1 to: `TableA.append(TableB.loc[~TableB.key.isin(TableA.key)], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: This solution does NOT work when there are multiple key columns (or at least it doesn't work without some extra finagling)!

Answer (score 84):

`indicator = True` in `merge` command will tell you which join was applied by creating new column `_merge` with three possible values:

- `left_only`
- `right_only`
- `both`

Keep `right_only` and `left_only`. That is it.

```
outer_join = TableA.merge(TableB, how = 'outer', indicator = True)

anti_join = outer_join[~(outer_join._merge == 'both')].drop('_merge', axis = 1)
```

easy!

Here is a comparison with a solution from piRSquared:

1) When run on this example matching based on one column, piRSquared's solution is faster.

2) But it only works for matching on one column. If you want to match on several columns - my solution works just as fine as with one column.

So it's up for you to decide.

[image]

Comment: in an anti join, should we not keep just `left_only` (and leave out `right_only` too along with `both' )

Comment: I think you're correct, @piedpiper.

Comment: Not nearly as intuitive as simply using `how='anti'` (or simply dplyr::anti_join() in R). dplyr definitely wins in regards to elegant code. At least polars has anti-join: https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/transformations/joins/

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242463/778533) using `how='outer'` and `indicator=True` of [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) inspired me to come up with this solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

TableA = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 3),
                      pd.Index(list('abcd'), name='Key'),
                      ['A', 'B', 'C']).reset_index()
TableB = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 3),
                      pd.Index(list('aecf'), name='Key'),
                      ['A', 'B', 'C']).reset_index()

print('TableA', TableA, sep='\n')
print('TableB', TableB, sep='\n')

TableB_only = pd.merge(
    TableA, TableB,
    how='outer', on='Key', indicator=True, suffixes=('_foo','')).query(
        '_merge == "right_only"')

print('TableB_only', TableB_only, sep='\n')

Table_concatenated = pd.concat((TableA, TableB_only), join='inner')

print('Table_concatenated', Table_concatenated, sep='\n')
```

Which prints this output:

```
TableA
  Key         A         B         C
0   a  0.035548  0.344711  0.860918
1   b  0.640194  0.212250  0.277359
2   c  0.592234  0.113492  0.037444
3   d  0.112271  0.205245  0.227157
TableB
  Key         A         B         C
0   a  0.754538  0.692902  0.537704
1   e  0.499092  0.864145  0.004559
2   c  0.082087  0.682573  0.421654
3   f  0.768914  0.281617  0.924693
TableB_only
  Key  A_foo  B_foo  C_foo         A         B         C      _merge
4   e    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.499092  0.864145  0.004559  right_only
5   f    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.768914  0.281617  0.924693  right_only
Table_concatenated
  Key         A         B         C
0   a  0.035548  0.344711  0.860918
1   b  0.640194  0.212250  0.277359
2   c  0.592234  0.113492  0.037444
3   d  0.112271  0.205245  0.227157
4   e  0.499092  0.864145  0.004559
5   f  0.768914  0.281617  0.924693
```

Answer (score 6):

Easiest answer imaginable:

```
tableB = pd.concat([tableB, pd.Series(1)], axis=1)
mergedTable = tableA.merge(tableB, how="left", on="key")

answer = mergedTable[mergedTable.iloc[:,-1].isnull()][tableA.columns.tolist()]
```

Should be the fastest proposed as well.

Answer (score 2):

One liner

```py
TableA.append(TableB.loc[~TableB.Key.isin(TableA.Key)], ignore_index=True)
```

`%%timeit` gives about the same timing as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have both tables `TableA` and `TableB` such that both `DataFrame` objects have columns with unique values in their respective tables, but some columns may have values that occur simultaneously (have the same values for a row) in both tables.

Then, we want to merge the rows in `TableA` with the rows in `TableB` that don't match any in `TableA` for a 'Key' column. The concept is to picture it as comparing two series of variable length, and combining the rows in one series `sA` with the other `sB` if `sB`'s values don't match `sA`'s. The following code solves this exercise:

```
import pandas as pd

TableA = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]])
TableB = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8], [9, 10, 0]])

removeTheseIndexes = []
keyColumnA = TableA.iloc[:,1] # your 'Key' column here
keyColumnB = TableB.iloc[:,1] # same

for i in range(0, len(keyColumnA)):
    firstValue = keyColumnA[i]
    for j in range(0, len(keyColumnB)):
        copycat = keyColumnB[j]
        if firstValue == copycat:
            removeTheseIndexes.append(j)

TableB.drop(removeTheseIndexes, inplace = True)
TableA = TableA.append(TableB)
TableA = TableA.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note this affects `TableB`'s data as well. You can use `inplace=False` and re-assign it to a `newTable`, then `TableA.append(newTable)` alternatively.

```
# Table A
   0  1   2
0  2  3   4
1  5  6   7
2  8  9  10

# Table B
   0   1  2
0  1   3  4
1  5   7  8
2  9  10  0

# Set 'Key' column = 1
# Run the script after the loop

# Table A
   0   1   2
0  2   3   4
1  5   6   7
2  8   9  10
3  5   7   8
4  9  10   0

# Table B
   0   1  2
1  5   7  8
2  9  10  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on one of the other suggestions, here's a function that should do it. Using only pandas functions, no looping. You can use multiple columns as the key as well. If you change the line `output = merged.loc[merged.dummy_col.isna(),tableA.columns.tolist()]`
 to `output = merged.loc[~merged.dummy_col.isna(),tableA.columns.tolist()]`
 you have a semi_join.

```
def anti_join(tableA,tableB,on):

   #if joining on index, make it into a column
   if tableB.index.name is not None:
       dummy = tableB.reset_index()[on]
   else:
       dummy = tableB[on]

   #create a dummy columns of 1s
   if isinstance(dummy, pd.Series):
       dummy = dummy.to_frame()

   dummy.loc[:,'dummy_col'] = 1

   #preserve the index of tableA if it has one
   if tableA.index.name is not None:
       idx_name = tableA.index.name
       tableA = tableA.reset_index(drop = False)
   else:
       idx_name = None

   #do a left-join
   merged = tableA.merge(dummy,on=on,how='left')

   #keep only the non-matches
   output = merged.loc[merged.dummy_col.isna(),tableA.columns.tolist()]

   #reset the index (if applicable)
   if idx_name is not None:
       output = output.set_index(idx_name)

   return(output)
```