# Compare two dataframes and returns difference based on the first df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two sample dfs as below:

```
df1
    Name    DOB
0   AMY     20100101
1   AMANDA  19990213
2   LEO     19920103
3   RIO     20200109
4   JEFF    20050314

df2
    Name    DOB
0   AMY     20100101
1   LEO     19920103
2   SEAN    19971123
3   BEN     20170119
4   SAM     20020615
5   YI      19930202
6   RICHAEE 19980919
7   MICHAEL 19920229
```

I want to compare the two dfs and the expected results look like:

```
Name      DOB
AMANDA    19990213
RIO       20200109
JEFF      20050314
```

I tried to use left join but didn't get what I expected

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['AMY','AMANDA','LEO','RIO','JEFF'],
                  'DOB':['20100101','19990213','19920103','20200109','20050314']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['AMY','LEO','SEAN','BEN','SAM','YI','RICHAEEL','MICHAEL'],
                  'DOB':['20100101','19920103','19971123','20170119','20020615','19930202','19980919','19920229']})

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name', how='left')
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi that's interesting, I wonder if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe

Comment: This is also known as an "anti-join" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516664/anti-join-pandas

`pd.merge(df1, df2[['Name']], on='Name', how='left', indicator=True).loc[lambda df: df['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop(columns='_merge')`

Comment: Use `df1[~df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name'])]`

Comment: @mcskinner thank you. Glad to learn the anti-join! Can you please post the solution to the answer and I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: or `pd.merge(df1, df2[['Name']], on='Name', how='left', indicator=True).loc[lambda x: x['_query']=='left_only'].drop(columns='_merge')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also known as an "anti-join".

```py
(pd.merge(df1, df2[['Name']], on='Name', how='left', indicator=True)
    .loc[lambda df: df['_merge'] == 'left_only']
    .drop(columns='_merge'))
#      Name       DOB
# 1  AMANDA  19990213
# 3     RIO  20200109
# 4    JEFF  20050314
```

Comment: this is duplicated od pandas merging 101, also don't copy solution in comments

Comment: @ansev OP asked for my comment to be translated to an answer for them. I see you have posted the same solution later. I think the valuable part of the answer was the vocabulary help to find "anti join", otherwise this is not easy to find.

Comment: Actually if you take a look, my comment predates both of yours by some minutes. Believe it or not, I came up with my solution independently.

Comment: also in this particular case it is much faster to use series.isin due to the simplicity of the dataframe. a boolean indexing with series.isin is much faster than using a complex method such as merge in addition to loc and drop