# Subset of columns from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (G) whose columns are “Client” and “TIV”.

I have another dataframe whose (B) columns are “Client”, “TIV”, “A”, “B”, “C”.

I want to select all rows from B whose clients are not in G. In other words, if there is a row in B whose Client also extsist in G then I want to delete it.

I did this:

```
x= B[B[‘Client’]!= G[‘Client’]
```

But it returned saying that “can only compare identically labeled Series Object”

I appriciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Comment: please share samples of dataframe so people can try it on their own machines

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an anti join. Check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516664/anti-join-pandas

Comment: @grymlin Thank you for your feedback. Anything would work so that's why I didn't put anything there. As long as Column of G is not selected in B, I am happy :)

Comment: @Chris I am trying my best to understand it actually. I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.isin` combined with `~` operator:

```
B[~B.Client.isin(G.Client)]
```

Comment: consider `G.Client.unique()` for the performance on larger data sets

Comment: Appreciated the feedback, @navid check this out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code snippet helps:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Client': [1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Client': [1,2,3,6,7]})
# Identify what Clients are in df1 and not in df2
clients_diff = set(df1.Client).difference(df2.Client)
df1.loc[df1.Client.isin(clients_diff)]
```

The idea is to filter `df1` on all clients which are not in `df2`