# Python -How to compare columns from two dataframe and create 3rd with new values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes that contains names. What I am need to do is to check which of the names in second dataframe are not present in the first dataframe.
For this example

```
list1 = ['Mark','Sofi','Joh','Leo','Jason']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns =['Names'])
```

and

```
list2 = ['Mark','Sofi','David','Matt','Jason']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2, columns =['Names'])
```

So basically I in this simple example we can see that David and Matt from second dataframe do not exist in the first dataframe.

I need programmatically to come up with 3rd dataframe that will have results like this:

```
Names
David
Matt
```

My first thought was to try using pandas merge function but I am unable to get the unique set of names from df2 that are not in df1.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the 3rd dataframe filtering the 2nd with a condition like this..

```
df3 = df2[~df2['Names'].isin(df1['Names'])]
```

Comment: hi, i tried that and it returns empty dataframe.

Comment: I've tested it and works ok for me. What's the output of doing this: `[name for name in df2["Names"] if name not in df1["Names"].values]` ?

Comment: In both cases i just get output with column "Names" and there is no value under it.

Comment: @Slavisha84 did you remove the `df2 = df1` from the second part of code? The solution works otherwise.

Comment: @PedroRocha - I did exactly what you pasted brother and for some reason in both cases i am getting empty dataframe.

Comment: There are two possibilities, 1. you have a previous error in your code like the `df2 = df1 = pd.Dataframe(list2, columns =['Names'])`when you are creating your df2. or 2. you have in your original data some names with spaces for example... then you can try this: `df3 = df2[~df2['Names'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().strip()).isin(df1['Names'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().strip()))]`

Comment: You were right. In my post i had an error with df2 = df1 =...
When i fixed that on my computer the solution you provided df3 = df2[~df2['Names'].isin(df1['Names'])]   worked like charm.  Thank you So much

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `merge` with `indicator`:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='Names', how='outer', indicator='exist')
   Names       exist
0   Mark        both
1   Sofi        both
2    Joh   left_only
3    Leo   left_only
4  Jason        both
5  David  right_only
6   Matt  right_only

>>> (df1.merge(df2, on='Names', how='outer', indicator='exist')
        .loc[lambda x: x.pop('exist') == 'right_only'])
   Names
5  David
6   Matt
```

Input dataframes:

```
list1 = ['Mark','Sofi','Joh','Leo','Jason']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns =['Names'])

list2 = ['Mark','Sofi','David','Matt','Jason']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2, columns =['Names'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach,

```
key_diff = set(df2.Names).difference(df1.Names)
where_diff = df2.Names.isin(key_diff)
df3 = df2[where_diff]
```

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516664/anti-join-pandas) for more